# How can I integrate mailchimp with asp.net_core project using Mailchimp.Net.V3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I wanna integrate Mailchimp into asp.net_core project.

I tried to use MailChimp.Net.V3 and MailChimp.Net.V3.Core package.

I couldn't install MailChimp.Net.V3 with one error(please check image below) and Couldn't handle tag with MailChimp.Net.V3.core package(Please check error msg below).

The project version of Microsoft.Extension.Http is 2.2.0.

How can I integrate MailChimp into my asp.net_core project?

[image: Error image]

Regards.

Comment: Why are you trying to use both packages? Use the .NET Core one.

Comment: First I tried to use Mailchimp.Net.V3 but failed as you can see from image. So I've installed Mailchimp.Net.V3.Core package , it works fine but I can't handle tag as you can see from image.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of MailChimp(version 5.0.0) requires `Microsoft.Extension.Http` version >= 3.1.8.

You may upgrade your asp.net core version to 3.1 and above.

Or just install the MailChimp.Net.V3(version 4.2.1).

Comment: Thanks @mj1313. It works for me. :)
Btw Can you please let me know how to send email to specific users using this package?
Ex : I wanna send mail to users who are tagged as "ABC".